# What is the best way to find the first occurrence of an item in a collection and update it

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, typescript

I have a collection in Javascript/Typescript

```
 [
  {"order":1,"step":"abc:","status":true},
{"order":2,"step":"xyz","status":true},
{"order":3,"step":"dec","status":false},
{"order":4,"step":"pqr","status":false},
{"order":5,"step":"tuv","status":false}
....
];
```

I need to write a function that every time its called it identifies the first occurrence of a false (Order:3 in the above example) and updates it to true. If the above method is called again now the next element (order:4 ) would have been updated. The steps that are false will always be below steps that are completed i.e true.

What's the best way (simplest, less code and elegant) to write this function? I can manually loop through using for each of the items in the collection, check for the first occurrence of false and then update it.

Comment: `for-loop`.. `If condition`.. `break` it if condition is being evaluated as `true`...

Comment: `(orders.filter(o=>!o.status)[0]||{}).status = true;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ES6 you can use this:

```
yourArray.find((element) => !element.status).status = true;
```

See [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and its compatibility table.

And note that this will fail if there is no entry with `status: false`. A quick and dirty fix could for example look like the one below. But that entirely depends on your use case.

```
(yourArray.find((element) => !element.status) || {}).status = true;
```

Comment: Got my +1 for not using element.status == false

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much what you described is how you would do it:

```
for (let order of orders) {
    if (!order.status) {
        order.status = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing. Is there a shorter ES6 version using Array map or so to further simply it? Thanks!!

Comment: It's using several ES6 components like `for..of`. Besides, I don't agree with writing something the shortest most convoluted way possible for the sake of it.

Answer (score 3):

When you look for the matching occurance you require, then insert a 'break' statement to stop the search.

Example:

```
    for( var i=0; i<recs.length; i++ ) {
        if ( recs[i]['status'] == false ) {
            recs[i]['status'] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a shorter ES6 version using Array map or so to further simply it? Thanks!!

Comment: You haven't specified which platform or environment you are running this on.  Using the above will absolutely work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lodash find method to find the first occurence of false status.

Sample Code

```
_.find(users, function(object) { return object.status === false });
```

[lodash find documentation link](https://lodash.com/docs#find)